# Multiple NavigationControllers in one ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a slideout menu created using SWRevealViewController. Each row of the slideout menu is connected to a NavigationController.
I would that two row of two different TableViewController are connected to the same ViewController with a show segue.

[image: This is part of my Storyboard]

When I navigate from the first NavigationController the ViewController work correctly and the description of the clicked cell is set in the navigation bar.

```
class Details: UIViewController {

var name:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = name

    print(name)

}
```

Instead, when I navigate from the second  NavigationController the ViewController doesn't work. The navigation bar is not shown, but the "name" parameter is printed.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Put condition in didSelectRowAtIndexPath like(if indexPth.row == 2) and navigate by coding

Comment: i think you are not using PUSH , u r used Present for navigation

Comment: Solved your problem or still facing same problem?

Comment: I've eliminated and recreated the show segue and the problem seems to have been resolved.
In my case, is the best solution connect two different navigationcontrollers to a single viewcontroller to show details through show segue? Or should I take another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(name)
    self.navigationItem.title = name

    if let navController = self.navigationController {
      navController.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    } else {
      print("There is no Navigation Controller. You may not be showing this controller using 'navigation push'")
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your code and put index no. and title of the cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
    case 2: name = "yourFirstNavigationTitleName"
        break
    case 3: name = "yourSecondNavigationTitleName"
        break
    default: break
    }

}
```